# Enter key press is not working in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on an event where in I want to trigger the search functionality of my page by pressing the enter key in my keyboard.

My code works perfectly with **known browsers** such as Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet explorer.

Results which are related to the entered keyword are showing up however when I tried the scenario in Safari nothing really happens it will just remain on the same page where it was in the first place.

The following code works in all browsers except Safari.

```js
    function enterKeyFindAJob(e, jobSearchLink) {
        var enterKey = 13;
        if (e.which == enterKey) {
            $('button[onclick^="javascript:findAJob"]').click();
        }
    }
```

```html
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-cta navigation-rotis-font" type="button" onclick="javascript:findAJob('@ViewBag.FindAJobButtonLink')" data-rel="@findJobsId" data-name="asset" aria-label="@TranslationService.GetTranslationByKey(General.Find)">
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.FindAJobButtonLink))
                    {
                       
                        <span class="btn-icon icon-find" style="margin-left: 0px;"></span>@TranslationService.GetTranslationByKey(General.Find)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        
                        <span class="btn-icon icon-find" style="margin-left: 0px;"></span>@TranslationService.GetTranslationByKey(General.Find)
                    }
                </button>
            </span>
```

Comment: Since you already use jQuery, so try to use that to bind keyUp event instead of write yourself, jQuery already cover browser compatibility.

Comment: @beibeizhu sorry, can you be more specific?

Comment: can i know how you trigger function enterKeyFindAJob? and u can use browser debug see whether its because of function not trigger or button not trigger.